# How to retrieve multiple values from a string into an array in powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm looking to find a way to retrieve all of the MX records listed in a string into a text file.
So far I've got a script that gives me an HTML output from which I've used:

```
$Records = Get-Content -Path "C:\NETESP\MXRecords\MXRecordsHTML.txt" | Select-String -SimpleMatch -Pattern "MX: "
```

This results in $Records containing a string of:

```
<DIV class="well transcript">&nbsp;&nbsp;0&nbsp;&nbsp;nsb.nic.uk&nbsp;&nbsp;156.154.101.3&nbsp;&nbsp;NON-AUTH&nbsp;&nbsp;Recieved 2 Referrals , 
rcode=&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;NS: ns.mainnameserver.com,NS: ns2.mainnameserver.com,&nbsp;&nbsp;<BR><BR>&nbsp;&nbsp;1&nbsp;&nbsp;ns2.
mainnameserver.com&nbsp;&nbsp;79.170.43.3&nbsp;&nbsp;AUTH&nbsp;&nbsp;Recieved 2 Answers , rcode=&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;MX: exchange
=engine01-20052-1.icritical.com/pref=10,MX: exchange=engine02-20052-2.icritical.com/pref=20,&nbsp;&nbsp;<BR><BR></DIV></DIV></DIV></SPAN><TD>mx: </TD>
```

Is there a way to get the MX records and preferences values into a text file?  Depending on which server this is run, there may be anywhere up to 6 MX records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your `Select-String` like so:

```
... | Select-String 'MX:\s*([^,]+)' -AllMatches | 
      Foreach {$_.Matches | Foreach {$_.Value}}
```

You need to create a capture group `([^,]+)` in your regex.  This will allow you to extract just that part of the matched text alter.  You will also want to specify `-AllMatches` if there can be more than one MX record per line.  After that you will want to enumerate each of the `Matches` and spit our their value (which will be the capture group text).

BTW this capture group assumes that each MX record ends with a comma.  If that's not the case, you'll need to find the appropriate regex to capture just the MX record from the surrounding text.